# Qt5 overlay widget not resizing properly

Tags: c++, qt5.5

I am trying to design a widget which overlaps another one. I successfully done it, but I am facing a little problem during the resize event of my `QMainWindow`.

I created an `OverlayView` widget, derived from `QWidget`. The constructor used is defined as follows:

> ```
> OverlayView::OverlayView(QWidget* widget, const QColor& color, float opacity, OverLayPosition position) :
>     QWidget(nullptr),
>     referenceWidget_(widget),
>     overlayPosition_(position),
>     opacity_(opacity),
>     overlayColor_(color)
> {
>     overlayRect_ = referenceWidget_->rect();
>     overlayRect_.setWidth(overlayRect_.width() * 0.05f);
>     setAutoFillBackground(false);
>     setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
>     setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
>     setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
> }
> ```

The `referenceWidget_` class member is a pointer to a widget which is used to get its size. In my project, I used my `QMainWindow`.

I have just made a little experiment to see if the `OverlayView` widget was resizing correctly:

> ```
> MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
>     QMainWindow(parent),
>     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
> {
>     QPlainTextEdit* pte = new QPlainTextEdit(this);
>     pte->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
>     setCentralWidget(pte);
>
>     overlayView_ = new OverlayView(this, QColor(0x33, 0x99, 0x38, 120));
>     overlayView_->setParent(this);
>
>     connect(this, SIGNAL(updateOverlaySize(const QRect&)), overlayView_, SLOT(updateOverlaySize(const QRect&)));
> }
> ```

The `OverlayView` widget is connected to the `updateOverlaySize` slot through the `updateOverlaySize` signal of my `QMainWindow` used as follows:

> ```
> void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
> {
>     QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
>     emit updateOverlaySize(rect());
> }
> ```

The `updateOverlaySize` slot of the `OverlayView` is defined like this:

> ```
> void OverlayView::updateOverlaySize(const QRect& rect)
> {
>     overlayRect_ = rect;
> }
> ```

Just for testing purposes, the overlay occupy the `QMainWindow`.

Finally, the overlay is drawn by redefining the `paintEvent` of the `OverlayView`:

> ```
> void OverlayView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
> {
>     QPainter painter(this);
>     painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
>     painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
>     painter.fillRect(overlayRect_, overlayColor_);
> }
> ```

Here is the result:

[image: Expected result]

Everything seems to be fine...

[image: Not an expected result]

...mmmh not really. The overlay stops to be resized when the size of the `QMainWindow` exceed a certain value.

The `QRect` object received from the `updateOverlaySize` slot shows correct values.

If someone could help me to fix this. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

I just ommited to update the geometry of my widget. According to Qt doc, the geometry property do this:

> This property holds the geometry of the widget relative to its parent
>   and excluding the window frame.
>
> When changing the geometry, the widget, if visible, receives a move
>   event (moveEvent()) and/or a resize event (resizeEvent()) immediately.
>   If the widget is not currently visible, it is guaranteed to receive
>   appropriate events before it is shown.
>
> The size component is adjusted if it lies outside the range defined by
>   minimumSize() and maximumSize().

The `overlayRect_` class member was updated successfully but not the size of my widget. This seems to be a problem.

Updating the geometry in the `updateOverlaySize` slot fixed this:

> ```
> void OverlayView::updateOverlaySize(const QRect& rect)
> {
>     overlayRect_ = rect;
>     setgeometry(rect);
> }
> ```

Now, the `size()` method of the `OverlayView` widget is returning its real size.